# libssh example file - exec formate error

Tags: gcc, c

I followed the ssh guide to create a [ssh connection](http://api.libssh.org/stable/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html) and after compiling... The execution of the file doesn't run. The error I get is:

```
./sshtest
bash: ./sshtest: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

and if I run as sudo

```
./sshtest: 1: ./sshtest: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've given the binary file r+x:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me  6328 Oct 21 01:54 sshtest
```

And here is how I am compiling:

```
gcc -Wall -c sshtest1.c  -o sshtest  -lssh
```

The computer info:

```
uname -a
Linux me 4.4.0-161-generic #189-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 27 08:10:16 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Anyone have any ideas on why the binary would fail to execute? Please let me know if a min viable build is needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man gcc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) clearly states:

> the -c option says not to run the linker.

It’s not a parameter to provide `*.c` files as you might have thought…

**Remove the `-c` option to get your program linked, thus creating an executable binary.**

```
gcc -Wall sshtest1.c -o sshtest -lssh
```

> I've given the binary file r+x

This is done automatically for *linked* binaries.

> if I run as sudo

Don’t use `sudo` as a silver bullet! Running a bad, not-well-understood program with `sudo` won’t make it work magically but may increase the harm it could do!

Comment: Thank you! I guess the reason why I used the -c flag was to not get the undefined reference to `ssh_get_server_publickey` and a few other functions... but the logic is sound. :)  is there any way that I could ask how to resolve the undefined reference part? or different question? :)

Comment: @newbartonline Well, trying to resolve “undefined reference” errors (which are errors of the linking phase) by not linking at all will make you not getting those messages but does not help you on the way toward the goal which is a linked, executable binary… You should start a new question and post your output containing particularly those linker errors.